# Unusual redux store configuration and protected routes

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I need helo about a react-redux project that I using for studying purposes:
https://github.com/arshdkhn1/ecommerce-site-template

What I don't understand is how the redux store is provided.

I can see the configureStore.js file but there is no reference to it in the entire project. Am I missing something?

In fact, I need to understand how it is working because I'm trying to create protected route pretty much like this tutorial: https://github.com/Remchi/reddice/blob/master/client/utils/requireAuth.js
which creates a high-order component and uses the connect function from react-redux. Unfortunately I get this error:

[image]

Probably because of how/where the redux store is configured.

Can someone explain me what is happening, how this store is working and maybe how to create a private route for the project?

Comment: Did you try to run the code that is present at https://github.com/arshdkhn1/ecommerce-site-template ? Does it run?

Comment: Yes it works perfectly. I don't understand how it works without the Provider tag in index.js

Comment: It works because it is not using Redux in any of its components. So there is no need of a Provider or configureStore. :)

Comment: My god hahahahha!!!! Why do I have to get through this kind of idiot phases at least once a week? Thank you very much! It was way simpler than I thought!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index.js should reference the configureStore.js and have a call like `const store = configureStore();` in it before the render call. Something like

```
....
import configureStore from './path/to/configureStore';
....
....
const store = configureStore();
ReactDOM.render(
   <Prodvider store={store}>
     <App/>
   <Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Yes, that what I was expecting, but in this project there is nothing like this and I don't understand how it works without this reference.